# org.xmlGetting exception while parsing XML.sax.SAXParseException: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, domparser

I am sending one query in the handler formed from WSDL file, its nothing
     but to execute a query if we don't have access to databse.
     the handler has only one xml tag inside which we have to write query which
     we want to execute then it will query database and return the response in xml format.
     i am executing a simple select query to get the details of one row.
     but in the response i am getting the below exception

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)

proper return response XML should be
<row>    
 <Vendor>
      <Number>
         <CountryCode>1</CountryCode>
         <AreaCode>23</AreaCode>
         <SubNumber>456</SubNumber>
      </Number>
 </Vendor>
</row>

in this <SubNumber> tag is giving error,
i am not aware of value inside this tag in database.


i followed the stack trace and piece of code which is throwing the exception is:
   DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();
```

can anyone please help me with this exception?
where to look for? any modification required?
do i need to check the tags in return data ? are those valid
basically Child1 tag is designed in such a way that it holds an XML inside it which will go and persist into one column of the table

Comment: can you maybe post the pure XML of the relevant line, including all tags?

Comment: Exception clearly showing you have something wrong with your xml, could you please show your xml document

Comment: Corrected my question and pasted the expected xml response

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is **invalid**

```
row-->Parent-->Child-->Child 1
```

You cannot have space in XML element name. Your xml element name **Child 1** is having a space.

XML elements name must follow these [naming rules.....](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp)

- Names can contain letters, numbers, and other characters
- Names cannot start with a number or punctuation character
- Names cannot start with the letters xml (or XML, or Xml, etc)
- Names cannot contain spaces

Comment: name is different actually for easiness to read i put it as child 1, and i corrected as Child1 in my question, i checked in my xml element throwing exception is in correct format, i suspect its value is causing the exception becasue log statement is fetching the tag name correctly but before value gets logged exception is coming at place i mentioned in my question DOMParser parser